# rewrite url wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

my wordpress url is like below i  want to rewrite it

http://twowebse.website/course-instance/course-2-19-21-jan-2018/?crse=result
to
http://twowebse.website/course-instance/course-2-19-21-jan-2018/crse/result

i have tried below rewrite but it does not seem to be working.maybe because of dynamic url comes between for eg.course-2-19-21-jan-2018

**course-instance=taxonomy

course-2-19-21-jan-2018=taxonomyterm**

**crse i am apending static query variable**

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse12965_query_varss' );
function wpse12965_query_varss( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'crse';
    return $query_vars;
}


add_action( 'init', 'wpse12065_inits' );
function wpse12065_inits()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'course-instance/(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?',
        'index.php?pagename=course-instance&$matches[2]&crse=$matches[4]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more info about what is "course-instance" page or post, what is "course-2-19-21-jan-2018" and what is "crse"

Answer (score 0):

Without having much knowledge on your structure I can guess your rewrite structure will be somewhat similar to the following,

```
add_rewrite_rule('^course-instance/([a-zA-Z]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)/([a-zA-Z]*)/([a-zA-Z]*)',
    'index.php?pagename=course-instance&page=$matches[2]&**some-key**=crse&crse=$matches[4]',
    'top'
);
```

remove **some-key** with the type of this keyword in your structure.

Otherwise remove 3rd parameter totally from your URL. By doing that your URL will be,

> http://twowebse.website/course-instance/course-2-19-21-jan-2018/result

```
add_rewrite_rule('^course-instance/([a-zA-Z]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)/([a-zA-Z]*)',
    'index.php?pagename=course-instance&page=$matches[2]&crse=$matches[3]',
    'top'
);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: course-instance=taxonomy        
 course-2-19-21-jan-2018=taxonomyterm